# How do I remove starting and ending parts of strings for each line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of timestamps containing only one timestamp on each line like `00:06:29:14` which follows as: hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. Now, I want to delete hours and milliseconds to get only the minutes and seconds like `06:29` from this certain list.

On Notepad++ I find `^[^:]+:(.+)$` replacing all with `$1` in Regular expression Search Mode, which gives me the result of only removing the hours part at the beginning.

I need a single code to both delete hours at the beginning and milliseconds at the end of each line to save a great chunk of my time to work smart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the match a bit more specific and replace with group 1

```
^\d{2}:(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQgjTr/1)

[image]

Or matching the hours, minutes and seconds:

```
^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d):\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fBzcuN/1)

Comment: I tried the first code you gave and it worked like I wanted, thank you!