# How do I add time to a list of timestamps in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Now, I have a list of timestamps which I asked how to remove hours and miliseconds from them here:
[How do I remove starting and ending parts of strings for each line in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069291/how-do-i-remove-starting-and-ending-parts-of-strings-for-each-line-in-notepad)

My next issue is I need to add 1 minute and 30 seconds (actually 90 seconds in total) to each timestamp on my list. For example from this:

```
01:12
01:45
02:06
```

To this:

```
02:42
03:15
03:36
```

How do I solve this math problem with using only one or two codes in Notepad++?

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor it (and regex) can't do calculation. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: How about Excel? I don't know how but I think it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the formula in Excel shown below:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1)+90)
```

+90 is simply plus 90 seconds, change this as you wish. This formula should be written in B1 cell but you can apply to entire B column while your timestamps should be listed in A column.

Make sure to select the right "Time format" after selecting the cells following: `Right Click > Format Cells... > Number > Time > Type > ... > OK`